# I am trying to place more than one UICollectionView on my ViewController but only one UICollectionView is running on the simulation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to create a `ViewController` with multiple horizontally scrolling view. To do this, I decided to use `UICollectionViews`. However, when I simulate my app, the only `UICollectionView` that pops up is the one in the else-statement provided in the code below the `allDealsCollectionView`.

I tried placing print statements to see if any of the if-statements were even used when running the app. However, the only statement that was printed also came from the one else-statement the `allDealsCollectionView`. I think that this means that the problem stems somewhere in the line creating the if-statements.

Below is a chunk of code from my extension of my `ViewController`.

```
extension ViewController:UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource{
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if collectionView == self.myFavoritesCollectionView{
        print(myEmptyArray.count)
       return myEmptyArray.count
    }
    else if collectionView == self.fastFoodCollectionView{
        return fastFoodArray.count
    }
    else if collectionView == self.DessertsCollectionView{
        return dessertsArray.count
    }
    else if collectionView == self.sitDownRestrauntsCollectionView{
        return sitDownArray.count
    }
    else if collectionView == self.otherThanFoodCollectionView{
        return otherArray.count
    }
    else {
        print(allDiscounts.list.count)

        return allDiscounts.list.count
    }
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if collectionView == self.myFavoritesCollectionView {
    let cell1 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "theLikes", for: indexPath) as? myLikesCollectionViewCell
    cell1?.companyLikedImage.image = UIImage(named: allDiscounts.list[myEmptyArray[indexPath.row]].imageName)
    cell1?.companyLikedName.text = allDiscounts.list[myEmptyArray[indexPath.row]].businessName
        print("collectionviewlikes")
    return cell1!
    }
    else if collectionView == self.fastFoodCollectionView {
        let cell2 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "theFast", for: indexPath) as? FastFoodCollectionViewCell
        cell2?.fastCompanyLikedImage.image = UIImage(named: allDiscounts.list[fastFoodArray[indexPath.row]].imageName)
        cell2?.fastCompanyLikedName.text = allDiscounts.list[fastFoodArray[indexPath.row]].businessName
        print("collectionviewfast")
        return cell2!

    }
    else if collectionView == self.DessertsCollectionView {
        let cell3 =   collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "theDesserts", for: indexPath) as? DessertsCollectionViewCell
        cell3?.dessertsCompanyLikedImage.image = UIImage(named: allDiscounts.list[dessertsArray[indexPath.row]].imageName)
        cell3?.dessertsCompanyLikedName.text = allDiscounts.list[dessertsArray[indexPath.row]].businessName
        print("collectionviewdesserts")
        return cell3!
    }
    else if collectionView == self.sitDownRestrauntsCollectionView {
        let cell4 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "theSits", for: indexPath) as? sitDownCollectionViewCell
        cell4?.sitCompanyLikedImage.image = UIImage(named: allDiscounts.list[sitDownArray[indexPath.row]].imageName)
        cell4?.sitCompanyLikedName.text = allDiscounts.list[sitDownArray[indexPath.row]].businessName
        print("collectionviewsit")
        return cell4!
    }
    else if collectionView == self.otherThanFoodCollectionView {
        let cell5 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "theOthers", for: indexPath) as? OtherCollectionViewCell
        cell5?.otherCompanyLikedImage.image = UIImage(named: allDiscounts.list[otherArray[indexPath.row]].imageName)
        cell5?.otherCompanyLikedName.text = allDiscounts.list[otherArray[indexPath.row]].businessName
        print("collectionviewother")
        return cell5!
    }
    else {
        let cell6 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "allDeals", for: indexPath) as? allDealsCollectionViewCell
        cell6?.companyLikedImage1.image = UIImage(named: allDiscounts.list[indexPath.row].imageName)
        cell6?.companyLikedName1.text = allDiscounts.list[indexPath.row].businessName
        print("collectionviewall")
        return cell6!
    }
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if collectionView == self.myFavoritesCollectionView {
    // handle tap events
    ViewController.searchStruct.buttonTag = myEmptyArray[indexPath.row]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotocompany1", sender: self)
    }
    else if collectionView == self.fastFoodCollectionView {
        ViewController.searchStruct.buttonTag = fastFoodArray[indexPath.row]
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotocompany1", sender: self)
    }
    else if collectionView == self.DessertsCollectionView {
        ViewController.searchStruct.buttonTag = dessertsArray[indexPath.row]
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotocompany1", sender: self)
    }
    else if collectionView == self.sitDownRestrauntsCollectionView {
        ViewController.searchStruct.buttonTag = sitDownArray[indexPath.row]
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotocompany1", sender: self)
    }
    else if collectionView == self.otherThanFoodCollectionView {
        ViewController.searchStruct.buttonTag = otherArray[indexPath.row]
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotocompany1", sender: self)
    }
    else {
        ViewController.searchStruct.buttonTag = indexPath.row
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotocompany1", sender: self)
    }
}
```

}

If the code runs there should be 6 `UICollectionViews` that all have different images and labels displayed instead of the one that already works and 6 that are being displayed empty.

Comment: Are all of your collectionviews' datasources set correctly? What does your `numberOfItems(inSection:)` look like and `numberOfSections(in:)`, if you override that? If you break in this function, or look at the console prints, do all of the if/else statements get hit when the app runs? If not, and you've ruled out the dataSource and numberOfXXX functions, then check your outlets and make sure they're all connected correctly so the logic above will work. Also, it's not the cause of your problem, but classes should be capitalized, vars like `DessertsCollectionView` should not.

Comment: Yess all of my datasources are set correctly. However, the if/else statements are not being hit when the app runs. Also, the outlets are all connected properly. This is why I am unsure of what the problem could be. Also, thank you for the information about proper capitalization, I will make changes to that now. If you have any other advice on how to fix this problem, I would sincerely appreciate it! @clarus

Comment: Can you show the code for `collectionView(_ :, numberOfItemsInSection:)` and `numberOfSections(in:)`, if you override that?

Comment: Do you have all these collectionviews in a tableview ?

Comment: There might be a possibility that methods -  collectionView(_ :, numberOfItemsInSection:) or numberOfSections(in:) are returning 0 for different collectionViews. or SizeForItem at indexPath might be returning 0 for all collectionViews.

Comment: I do not have the `UICollectionViews` in a table. Will that fix my problem? @RajeshKumarR

Comment: I added all the code from the `extension`. Can you see any problems in these? Thanks! @Friend

Answer (score 0):

You need to check correctly if current collectionView is equal current class

```
if collectionView.isEqual(DessertsCollectionView) {
   //current collectionView working
}
```

For DessertsCollectionView custom class must be defined.

Comment: what do you mean that the DessertsCollectionView custom class must be defined?

Comment: For each collection that you use, you need to create your own class with custom name (like DessertsCollectionView)  and inherit from UICollectionView.If you use storyboard, for each collectionView define class that you created. @Nebraska2Texas

Comment: I had already created classes for each CollectionViewCell and defined the class for each cell in the storyboard for the cells. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Nebraska2Texas Yes, and you need created class for each collectionView too